# call system command within MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm calling an exe command :

```
myCmd = fullfile('working',myCommand.bat');
[status,message] = system(myCmd )

status = 0
message = 
processing value ...
complete
activating command ...
complete
```

How could I get some text from message ?
For example i would like to get the "first text" and "complete" to check the first action is completed ?

Thanks

Comment: what are you calling with `system`? `message` will contain what the called executable returns to the cmd. you could write a short executable which returns a message and called it togehter with your actual function.

Comment: I'm calling an exe command which starts a software and I would like to get some text from the message , is there a way to do it ?

Comment: use `regexp` to parse the `message` returned from `system`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by opening a DOS prompt inside the MATLAB prompt?

Comment: @lola does it work finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `echo` command to include a return message:

```
[status,message] = system('yourCommand && echo hello world' )
```

will return:

```
message =
      hello world
```

Generally you will need to create a string where you cascade all your commands connected with `&&`. One of the commands could then be `echo something`.

Regarding your edit:

```
output = 'processing value ...'    
command = ['cd ' myCMD ' && myCommand.bat' ' && echo ' output];
[status,message] = system( command )
```

will call `myCommand.bat` and return "processing value...".

Comment: you mean : [status,message] = system(cmd.exe ,'-echo myText')

Comment: no, I mean what I have written. But you actually don't want to call `cmd.exe` right? by using `system` you're already inside the cmd. Be aware that `yourCommand` has a kind of return value, so that the cmd knows when to call the next command. Then you have to combine them with `&&` like `system('echo hello && echo world' )` which returns hello world in two lines. System requieres a string! `cmd.exe` is no string. you can use `strcat` to create a complete command in advance

Comment: No, I want to call cmd.exe to execute it and get the results message to check if it is correct

Comment: then `cmd.exe` is just a bad example to try, because it won't return `status = 0` the way you call it and hence won't write `message`.

Comment: have a look at the last edit. If you can not make it work now, you have to be much more specific, so I could rebuilt your certain case.