# get message form MATLAB command line

Tags: matlab

how to get log message from MATLAB command window ?
is there a function that allows doing that ?

example :

I call a function `myFun()` and this function return a boolean 0,1 but I would like to check what does it display as message in the MATLAB command

Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase the question or provide an example of what you would like to see? I'm not sure that I entirely understand your question.

Comment: Does the `diary` command do what you want? See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/diary.html

Comment: it is already the third time you ask this question, the first time [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094421/call-system-command-within-matlab), you weren't happy but you accepted. You never specified what was wrong with my solution. Your second question, I think it was yesterday, you deleted as nobody reacted. And now again. I would recommend to you to write a clear and distinctive question with everything you already tried and what exactly was wrong with all your attempts, including errors. If that does not help, you have enough rep for a bounty. Somebody will find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe what you want is to add things like:

```
disp('my function is doing step 1')

disp('my function is doing step 2')
```

etc. at the respective locations along your function.

Which does the same as leaving a string without a semicolon at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

`evalc` should in principle do the trick:

```
>> s = evalc('disp(''hello'')')
s =
hello
```

Similarly you could use `diary`, which however does introduce somewhat more overhead due to  file io:

```
diary_file = tempname();
diary(diary_file);
myFun(); % will dump the console-output to diary_file
diary('off');
% read the output
console_output = fileread(diary_file);
```

Comment: my function returns  o or 1

Comment: is it possible to parse console_output to check the content ?

Comment: Well of course you can, it will be a simple string. If it's really only "0" or "1" (without any other characters around) you could actually do a `result = str2double(console_output);`.